# Xamarin.Forms System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am brand new to Xamarin.Forms projects.  I have created a project with VS2019 which has not been modified in any way, added a Pixel 2 Pie 9.0 - Api 28 emulator within the Android Device Manager.  When I try to run the project on the android emulator, I am unable to run my app, with the following exception in my error list:

```
Error       XARDF7004: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.RemoveDirFixed.RunTask()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()
```

Since I am simply using a basic project template generated by VS2019, this has to be a bug on Microsofts end.  How can I fix their error?

Comment: does your project/solution/directory structure contain any non-standard characters?

Comment: @Jason I don't believe so, but it is quite long, I can try a shorter path and maybe that will fix it: C:\Users\david\Dropbox\Projects\Visual Studio\PriceWatch\PriceWatch\PriceWatchXamarinForms\PriceWatchXamarinForms This structure was generated by IDE, not quite sure why some folders are redundant.

Comment: VS generates a LOT of files during build, I'm not sure placing your project in a Dropbox folder is a good idea.

Comment: @Jason changing my solution location to C:\Projects\<Solution Folder> fixed the problem.  I had them in my DropBox folder because if something happens to my PC I don't want to lose my work.  Should I just use a USB stick for backup instead?

Comment: learn to use source control.  github and Azure both offer free repos

Comment: @Jason Thanks.  I am still learning, but I will take your advice on that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It had to do with the character length of my solutions folder.

```
C:\Users\david\Dropbox\Projects\Visual Studio\PriceWatch\PriceWatch\PriceWatchXamarinForms\PriceWatchXamarinForms
```

(This bloated structure was generated by the IDE, everything after the Visual Studio folder)

I changed it to `C:\Projects\PriceWatch\PriceWatchXamarinForms` and then it worked.

Comment: I've been working on this.. and I think the mark is somewhere around 64 characters. I've tried in several folders, manipulating names, spaces, hyphens, etc. Spaces don't seem to affect it, but somewhere a round the 64 mark has: "C:\tmp\TestFolder\AdditionalCharacters\Subfolder\OneMoreFolder\VideoDe" works. BUT, I think this may actually be related to an inner file; continuing to check.

Comment: I found a more specific error after playing further which lead me here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/521034/failed-to-create-javatypeinfo.html#

This says there's a MAX_PATH problem on Windows.

Comment: The error that lead me there, after resolving the above, was: "System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

Answer (score 4):

I our case the reason was that some of our third party dependencies (api assemblies) forced us to set Properties > Android Options > Linking to "Sdk and User Assemblies" instead of "None".

Hope this helps someone...
Bad error message.

Answer (score 1):

I recently experienced this with VS 16.9.2 AND 16.9.3. And this is how I fixed it.

1. Open android SDK manager (make sure you have at least API level 29 or 30 checked).
2. Click on the Tools tab right next to Platforms Tab(that you will have landed on)
3. Ensure that the following are installed:
   -***> ANDROID SDK command-line tools, Platform-tools, build tools, Android emulator and NDK***
4. P.S. It might take a while to download and install.
   Don't forget to create your emulator of choice once the above steps have been successfully completed.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix this problem by starting an adb shell and go into the app directory:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.fips.SorterApp/files
```

then

```
rm -rf .__override__
```

and deploy worked again

Answer (score 0):

There are many causes for this error.

Mine was caused by having invalid directories in my system PATH.  Removing the invalid entries and restarting my environment (either by killing and restarting all explorer.exe processes or by restarting machine) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this is the `subst` command it creates a "new" drive at a folder location. Then you open the sln file from the new drive.

```
 subst e: C:\Users\david\Dropbox\Projects\Visual Studio\PriceWatch\
```

then open the e: drive in file explorer or the open solution dialog

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours on this error and none of the suggestions regarding changing the path worked for me. What did work is I went into the android simulator and went into app settings and forced stop, as well as clearing storage and cache.

Answer (score 0):

There is an another one you need to consider to resolve the System.Argument Exception having "An element with X already exists in NameScope". To solve this issue try to check if your code behind is having two InitializeComponent(); in the constructor.

Because, when the InitiallizeComponent(); is declared twice the system tries to Initialize the same components with the same name, so getting the exception "An element with X already exists in NameScope".