# The ResolveAssemblyReference task failed unexpectedly on VS 2017 with target framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Can anyone help fix this please?
i am facing this issue when i build any of my projects.
i am running Windows 10 version 1909, OS build 18363.836, VS 2017.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018: The "ResolveAssemblyReference" task failed unexpectedly.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyFoldersExCache.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<.ctor>b__0(AssemblyFoldersExInfo assemblyFolder)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass42_0`2.<PartitionerForEachWorker>b__1()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object <p0>)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.PartitionerForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](Partitioner`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 simpleBody, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyFoldersExCache..ctor(AssemblyFoldersEx assemblyFoldersEx, FileExists fileExists)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyFoldersExResolver.LazyInitialize()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyFoldersExResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameExtension assemblyName, String sdkName, String rawFileNameCandidate, Boolean isPrimaryProjectReference, Boolean wantSpecificVersion, String[] executableExtensions, String hintPath, String assemblyFolderKey, ArrayList assembliesConsideredAndRejected, String& foundPath, Boolean& userRequestedSpecificFile)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyResolution.ResolveReference(IEnumerable`1 jaggedResolvers, AssemblyNameExtension assemblyName, String sdkName, String rawFileNameCandidate, Boolean isPrimaryProjectReference, Boolean wantSpecificVersion, String[] executableExtensions, String hintPath, String assemblyFolderKey, ArrayList assembliesConsideredAndRejected, String& resolvedSearchPath, Boolean& userRequestedSpecificFile)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.ResolveReference(AssemblyNameExtension assemblyName, String rawFileNameCandidate, Reference reference)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.ResolveAssemblyFilenames()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.ComputeClosure()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.ComputeClosure(IEnumerable`1 remappedAssembliesValue, ITaskItem[] referenceAssemblyFiles, ITaskItem[] referenceAssemblyNames, ArrayList exceptions)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference.Execute(FileExists fileExists, DirectoryExists directoryExists, GetDirectories getDirectories, GetAssemblyName getAssemblyName, GetAssemblyMetadata getAssemblyMetadata, GetRegistrySubKeyNames getRegistrySubKeyNames, GetRegistrySubKeyDefaultValue getRegistrySubKeyDefaultValue, GetLastWriteTime getLastWriteTime, GetAssemblyRuntimeVersion getRuntimeVersion, OpenBaseKey openBaseKey, GetAssemblyPathInGac getAssemblyPathInGac, IsWinMDFile isWinMDFile, ReadMachineTypeFromPEHeader readMachineTypeFromPEHeader)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018: ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssemblyFoldersExCache.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<.ctor>b__0(AssemblyFoldersExInfo assemblyFolder)`enter code here`
```

Comment: [Related](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/5323). Especially [this](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/5323#issuecomment-621613169) comment.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Thank you,  i tried as you suggested - created a console application and tried to build it, it worked!
also i have tried repair as well, and even i have tried uninstall and installed again the VS. but my asp.net projects its still not working.

Comment: no actually,
output window of the console application still says
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: So I am sure that it is related to your project itself. Did you do any changes to your project before facing this error? Besides, is the path of your project too long and beyond the system regulation? If so, you should change to shorten the length of the project path.

Comment: all the projects on my machine were working already, even i have tried getting latest from  version control as well. still i am not able to close this :(

Answer (score 1):

> The ResolveAssemblyReference task failed unexpectedly on VS 2017 with
>   target framework 4.7.2

I think the issue is related to your asp net project itself. I wonder whether you did some changes before facing these errors or it is an old project which you migrated it into VS2017.

You could try the following steps to troubleshoot your issue:

**Suggestion**

First, make sure that these errors are not from your code. If these are from code, you can enter the error code location in the error list and then you can fix them.

**1)** Please check whether the path of your project is too long and beyond the system, if so, you should change to shorten the length of the project path.  Hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59402317/xamarin-forms-system-argumentexception-illegal-characters-in-path).

**2)** then close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder. Then restart your project agian.

**3)** run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**NuGet Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**

Then also run `Get-Project –All | Add-BindingRedirect`

**In addition**, if all of the steps do not work, I think you could try to create a new net framework 4.7.2 project and then migrate the content of the old project into the new project.

Also, copy the `packages.config` file into the new project and then run `update-package -reinstall` to install all the related packages automatically as step 3 suggested.

**Besides**, please share the `xxx.csproj` of your project with us and it will help us locate the issue more quickly.

Comment: thank you for your kind reply,
1 - No i do not have my Path that long, also console applications are still working from the same folder as well.
2 - I tried deleting .vs along with bin and obj folders as well, it did not work
3 - i tried to run this command, after this i am not able to build the project at all, it keeps building then i had to role back 

I tried to create a new project (empty) and tried to build it, it worked all fine,
still i am trying to get it fixed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i have tried creating a new console application and it gets build smooth, whereas my web projects are not working at all (even new asp.net mvc project also gets build successfully)  
i also tried to build one of my project with MSBuild utility, does it has to do anything with all this?

Comment: We will wait for you:)