# ADB1000 Deployment failed in Xamarin Forms project (Illegal characters in path)

Tags: xamarin.forms, adb, visual-studio-2019, illegal-characters

I am working in **Xamarin.Forms** app in **Visual Studio 2019** and trying to deploy my app to my phone. Each build I do I get a

> ADB100: Deployment failed System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path

I am not sure how to amend this issue, there are no **proj** files. I am at the mercy of this forum I thank you in advance if your able to help.

[image: deployment error]

Comment: Is this a new project? Can you share the path of the project?

Comment: new yes! C:\Users\brian\source\repos\birthdays

Comment: This does not occur at any line of any specific file, the error log is blank for file, and 0 for line

Comment: Did you try the classic: Delete obj and bin folders and try again ;)

Comment: I have and no change

Comment: yeah have already tried that, nothing same result

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59402317/xamarin-forms-system-argumentexception-illegal-characters-in-path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin.Forms System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59402317/xamarin-forms-system-argumentexception-illegal-characters-in-path)

Comment: the filepath is too long copy your folder to desktop or paste directly to your drive without any folder hierarchy

Comment: tried all of the above and no resolution.. i think im going to start again

Comment: You could try to copy it to a new project and test it.

Answer (score 1):

A new project worked without issue on the original emulator.

I was able to get my deployment going on a different emulator.

Environment:
Visual Studio: Version 16.8.5
OS: Windows 10
Xamarin Android SDK: 11.1.0.26