# Visual Studio Community 2019 Update affects Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a big problem with Visual Studio Community 2019 V16.9.0. I have installed this update and when I tried to run again my Xamarin.Android project it's led to crash. I have tried to make a new project, the name was auto-generated "App3" because I don't want to modify anything in order to see that the project can be built successfully. The build failed as you can see in the picture below.

[image: Errors]

VS also can't see the References for the project.

[image: Solution Explorer]

I have tried to repair the SDK but it doesn't help because the reparation has failed.

I let you als the errors that had been generated.

```
Build started...
Starting emulator Nexus_5X_API_29 ...
1>------ Build started: Project: App3, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004:    at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004:    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004:    at Xamarin.Android.Tools.ProcessUtils.<FindExecutablesInDirectory>d__9.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/ProcessUtils.cs:line 177
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004:    at Xamarin.Android.Tools.ProcessUtils.<FindExecutablesInPath>d__8.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/ProcessUtils.cs:line 168
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004:    at Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdkBase.<GetAllAvailableAndroidNdks>d__73.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/Sdks/AndroidSdkBase.cs:line 153
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004:    at Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdkWindows.<GetAllAvailableAndroidNdks>d__43.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/Sdks/AndroidSdkWindows.cs:line 257
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004:    at Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdkBase.GetValidNdkPath(String ctorParam) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/Sdks/AndroidSdkBase.cs:line 128
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004:    at Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdkBase.Initialize(String androidSdkPath, String androidNdkPath, String javaSdkPath) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/Sdks/AndroidSdkBase.cs:line 71
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004:    at Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdkWindows.Initialize(String androidSdkPath, String androidNdkPath, String javaSdkPath) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/Sdks/AndroidSdkWindows.cs:line 310
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004:    at Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdkInfo..ctor(Action`2 logger, String androidSdkPath, String androidNdkPath, String javaSdkPath) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/AndroidSdkInfo.cs:line 18
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.RefreshAndroidSdk(String sdkPath, String ndkPath, String javaPath, TaskLoggingHelper logHelper)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveSdks.RunTask()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(64,5): error XARSD7004:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin.Forms System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59402317/xamarin-forms-system-argumentexception-illegal-characters-in-path)

Comment: @IanKemp unfortunately it didn't help. I think it's a bug from MS and probably will release another version soon that will fix the damages.

Comment: You could report it on the [Xamarin.Fomrs Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your system PATH environment variable in Windows System Advanced Settings. I had the same issue. After few days seeking for solution I noticed a strange empty entry in PATH. After deleting it the error XARSD7004 is finally gone!!!
The bug was probably casued by VS 2019 16.9.2 update in my case. I wrote this solution for others not to loose few days fighting it like me. I reinstalled Xamarin, SDK, tried tons of different settings and even thought of reinstalling whole VS.